# <label> applied CSS appears at bottom of textarea. How to hide it?

Tags: css, wordpress, label, textarea

I'm using Contact Form 7 plugin in Wordpress to add a form. I'm running into a problem when using textarea in the form; I have my  tags styled with `background-color: #0090bc;`. However, it is displaying below the textarea also.

[image: <label> CSS below [textarea]]

***FRONT-END CODE FOR HOWARD E***

Hope this helps

```
<p><label>Aim of Website<br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-website-goal-1"><textarea name="your-website-goal-1" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="e.g. 'I just need a website so that I can link people to it through social media'..."></textarea></span></label></p>
```

<strike>I've tried wrapping it in a div and setting the CSS</strike>

```
.full-spread textarea{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
position:relative;
}
```

[image]

Although this technically fixes the issue I run into another one where there is no gap between the next element below this div then - and I can't figure out how to resolve that new issue then either.

This, however, doesn't solve my issue so you can ignore it.

Here is my code to support the screenshots:

```
<label>Aim of Website[textarea your-website-goal-1 placeholder "e.g. 'I just need a website 
so that I can link people to it through social media'..."]</label>
</div>


<label>Websites you've seen online that you like
[textarea influenced-website-1 placeholder "e.g. ''www.thiswebsite.com' - I like how this website details everything on one page'..."]</label>
<div>
```

My label tags are target with this CSS:

```
.wpcf7-form label {
    text-align:center;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 5px;
    background-color: #0090bc;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: What you've posted won't help. Contact form 7 wraps every tag in a span, so you need to review the front end output and see how it all lays out.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your reply a bit? From what I posted why isn't it helpful? Also, could you elaborate on "reviewing my front-end output and see how it all lays out"? That's why I came here for help.

Comment: You need to share the output of the form, not the form code to debug your css.  You need to share what comes on the front end and not in your admin page.  I don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: @HowardE Does what I've added help?

Answer (score 0):

Targeting this textarea by adding `margin-bottom:-1%;` it removes the extra bit of the label tag showing under the textarea

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-website-goal-1"><textarea name="your-website-goal-1" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="e.g. 'I just need a website so that I can link people to it through social media'..."></textarea></span>
```